# dc multi-select disabling not working

Tags: multi-select, dc.js, crossfilter

I am plotting two bar charts using cross filter. The graphs are coming out fine. However, I want to disable multi-select for the first bar chart.This is what I am trying to do:

```
var barChart2 = dc.barChart("#dc-mv-chart");  
var depValue = facts.dimension(function(d) {return d.d;});
var depValueGroupSum = depValue.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.g;});
var mvValue = facts.dimension(function(d,i) {return d.b;});
      var mvValueGroupSum = mvValue.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.g;});  
      barChart1.width(1200)
            .height(200)
            .margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 80})
            .dimension(depValue)                                
            .group(depValueGroupSum)                            
            .transitionDuration(800)
            .centerBar(true)    
            .gap(10)                                            
            .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["AUTO & TIRES", "BABY", "CLOTHING", "ELECTRONICS", "GARDEN", "GROCERY", "HEALTH", "HOME", "HOME IMPROVEMENT", "PHOTO", "SPORTS", "TOYS", "VIDEO GAMES"]))
            .elasticY(true)

            .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)   
            .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
            .renderlet(function (chart) {
            chart.selectAll("dc-department-chart").on("click", function (d) {
            chart.filter(null);
            chart.filter(d.M);
        })
        });


        //barChart1.filter = function() {}

          barChart2.width(600)
            .height(300)
            .margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 80})
            .dimension(mvValue)                             
            .group(mvValueGroupSum)                         
            .transitionDuration(800)
            .centerBar(true)    
            .gap(20)                                            
            .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["SEM", "SEO", "SOCIAL", "CSE", "ORGANIC", "MOBILEWEB", "AFFILIATES", "EMAIL", "DISPLAYADS"]))
            .elasticY(true)
            .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
            .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal);      

          // Render the Charts
          dc.renderAll();
```

This, however, doesn't disable multi-select for the first graph. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've got the wrong selector there, you're attempting to select the chart id instead of the bars within it. Try `.selectAll('rect.bar')` instead.

Comment: I am getting this error:Cannot read property 'isFiltered' of undefined . can it be because I have null values at many places(not all, though) for d.M ??

Comment: I guess no because I replaced my nulls with zero and I still get the error.

Comment: Also, can you take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24992280/enable-default-selection-in-bar-chart-of-dc

Comment: Yeah, that does sound like `d.M` is undefined, which would not filter in a useful way.  Usually you should filter on the same data that is the dimension key - in this case it looks like `d.d`.

Comment: Time to fire up the debugger, put a breakpoint on that line, and see what is wrong with what you're passing to `.filter`!

Comment: Gordon, two things..I have noticed that multi-select is disabled using the above code snippet but 1) the selected bar doesn't get highlighted 2)the other charts are no longer being filtered by the click on the bar. Infact the clicked selection becomes visible only when I put a filter on any of the other graphs.

Comment: So, two thins that I need is: 1)the on click event should trigger a color change in the bar selected and 2) rest of the graphs should still be filtered with this selection. How can I make this work? Any suggestions ??