# Enable default selection in bar-chart of dc

Tags: multi-select, dc.js, crossfilter

So, I have two bar charts plotted using cross-filter and dc. This is how my code looks like:

```
var barChart2 = dc.barChart("#dc-mv-chart");  
var depValue = facts.dimension(function(d) {return d.d;});
var depValueGroupSum = depValue.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.g;});
var mvValue = facts.dimension(function(d,i) {return d.b;});
      var mvValueGroupSum = mvValue.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.g;});  
      barChart1.width(1200)
            .height(200)
            .margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 80})
            .dimension(depValue)                                
            .group(depValueGroupSum)                            
            .transitionDuration(800)
            .centerBar(true)    
            .gap(10)                                            
            .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["AUTO & TIRES", "BABY", "CLOTHING", "ELECTRONICS", "GARDEN", "GROCERY", "HEALTH", "HOME", "HOME IMPROVEMENT", "PHOTO", "SPORTS", "TOYS", "VIDEO GAMES"]))
            .elasticY(true);


        //barChart1.filter = function() {}

          barChart2.width(600)
            .height(300)
            .margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 80})
            .dimension(mvValue)                             
            .group(mvValueGroupSum)                         
            .transitionDuration(800)
            .centerBar(true)    
            .gap(20)                                            
            .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["SEM", "SEO", "SOCIAL", "CSE", "ORGANIC", "MOBILEWEB", "AFFILIATES", "EMAIL", "DISPLAYADS"]))
            .elasticY(true)
            .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
            .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal);      

          // Render the Charts
          dc.renderAll();
```

However, in my first graph(i.e. barChart1), I want one of the bars to be selected by default i.e. 'Auto & Tires' and also, in the first chart at any time I want only one selection to be made(i.e. disable multi-select for the first graph) So this is what I want to know:

1. Is it possible to disable multi-select (keeping in mind that there should be only one bar selected in the graph at a time) for a bar graph plotted using dc?
2. If 1 is possible, then is it possible to keep a default selected bar all the time(by all the time, I mean, on first load when no selection has been made and also,a situation when, say, the user selects 'SPORTS') and deselects it.On de-selection, the graph being shown should be for 'Auto & Tires' which is my default selection)

I am quite new to using dc and cross-filter and haven't found much about the things that I want to implement.So, any help or suggestion of any kind will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you were on the right track with your other post setting up your own onClick event.  That's currently the best way to change the filtering behavior, although there are some proposals to make the filtering behavior configurable, including one PR I hope to merge this week.

Comment: 'replace' worked.!!. Thanks a lot.!!

Comment: Hey Gordon, can you have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180398/dc-cross-filter-not-working..Is it some issue with dc or am I going wrong somewhere?Please, do look into it once